# News onto hub news webpart from communication site vs team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, hub-site, sharepoint-news

I am new to SharePoint and struggling with news.

I have a hub site which acts as a home page for all teams, with each group having a dedicated site associated to the hub.

I was hoping that the 'Marketing' site could publish news articles that would display in the hub site news web part.

However, when selecting the source for the webpart I am unable to see any of the sites associated with this hub?

[image]

Is there a way to manipulate this? If not, What have I done wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have posted at least one News Post in each site, I have seen sites not show up as a choice until someone has first published a page.  Also, does your account have permission to view content on all of those sites?    
  
Choosing "All sites in the hub" seems to work regardless, and also automatically includes any future sites that get create and connected to the hub, so unless there is a specific reason to exclude some of your sites, that may be a safer option.

Answer (score 0):

The differance is that only 'Communication' sites can be used as sources for news (and events).

For some reason, team sites do not appear - i do not know why.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should Edit your question and add this additional information to your question, rather than posting it as answer. 
Users looking to help out by providing answers may end up skipping your question because it looks on the listing page like someone has already submitted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both Team sites (classic or modern) and Communication sites are supported in News Source.

If all sites are newly built in your environment, it might take some time for the sites to appear in this list.

It is managed by SharePoint directly so there is not really much you can do to fasten this process.

You can try to find the team sites by entering site names or URLs in the input box “Search by title or enter a URL” and then select the returned site.

[image]

Comment: this just not working for me. dunno why

Comment: @terryg still not working?

Comment: nope - i've had to create another com site seperate from the team site